LazyHStack not respecting height of contents when in a ScrollView
I have two child views, one smaller than the other. I want to place them in a LazyHStack which will be in a horizontal ScrollView. This horizontal ScrollView is itself in a Vertical ScrollView.
However, the resulting view is always the height of the smaller child view. Here's an example:
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack {
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    LazyHStack(alignment: .top) {
                        createView(
                            title: "Short View",
                            height: 100
                        )
                        
                        createView(
                            title: "Long View",
                            height: 500
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func createView(title: String, height: CGFloat) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: height)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
}

maxHeight: .infinity and .fixedSize() don't solve the issue.
Is this expected when using a LazyHStack? I need it to be lazy.

Yes, it is expected when using a LazyHStack. See the answer to SwiftUI: Nested scroll views on opposite axis for some possible workarounds.

That's exactly what I needed but couldn't find. Thank you so much.
